# Converting Ising Hamiltonian to a Circuit in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, optimization, qaoa

I tried to solve a 2-node TSP ([travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)) by implementing QAOA on Qiskit. The graph looks like:

[image]

Then I used the related Qiskit functions to convert the graph to the QUBO and map it into Ising Hamiltonian, which results:

```
Problem name: TSP

Minimize
  1.7845421369027294*x_0_0*x_1_1 + 1.7845421369027294*x_0_1*x_1_0

Subject to
  Linear constraints (4)
    x_0_0 + x_0_1 == 1  'c0'
    x_1_0 + x_1_1 == 1  'c1'
    x_0_0 + x_1_0 == 1  'c2'
    x_0_1 + x_1_1 == 1  'c3'

  Binary variables (4)
    x_0_0 x_0_1 x_1_0 x_1_1

Offset: 10.030439616062282
Ising Hamiltonian:
-0.44613553422568236 * IIIZ
- 0.4461355342256823 * IIZI
- 0.4461355342256823 * IZII
- 0.4461355342256823 * ZIII
+ 2.2845421369027292 * IIZZ
+ 2.2845421369027292 * IZIZ
+ 0.44613553422568236 * IZZI
+ 0.44613553422568236 * ZIIZ
+ 2.2845421369027292 * ZIZI
+ 2.2845421369027292 * ZZII
```

Based on the shown Ising Hamiltonian, I built a circuit for the problem unitary as following:

[image]

I then ran QAOA with the circuit of 2 layers (2 angles each for gamma and beta) and COBLYA optimizer. The result shows:

[image]

While 0110 and 1001, which are the solutions to the problem, outstand most of the others, 0000 has the highest counts, which is not correct.

Have I done anything wrong with regards to building the circuit from the Hamiltonian?

Comment: Could you post some more of your code, eg the implementation of the QAOA (are you using Qiskit's QAOA functionality or a custom one?)